# How do I use where clause in the sql trigger?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a trigger where the account balance is automatically updated from the transaction table, but I am not being able to update a particular table. My trigger changes the account balance of every customer. I want to know how I can use where clause to make it customer-specific. Here is what I have:

```
create trigger trig_one
on dbo.transactions
for insert, update, delete
as begin
    declare @amount int
    select @amount = (select amount from inserted)

    update dbo.account set balance = balance + @amount

end
```

Please help me out. Thanks!

Comment: Are transactions really going to be *updated* and *deleted*? You'd typically make your transaction table insert-only, so the balance of a customer really is the sum of all the amounts in all the transactions (including adjustments downwards). Things get much more complicated if (for example) you have to *decrease* a customers balance based on a transaction with a positive amount getting deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You structure the query like this:

```
update dbo.account
    set balance = balance + i.amount
    from dbo.account a join
         inserted i
         on i.accountid = a.accountid ;
```

(The join key is whatever the join key should be.)

Of course, you need to do the same thing for the deleted.  Note:  this will work for multiple rows being inserted.  That is handy.  Your version will fail unexpectedly.